# Input to execute a dos command bat

Tags: batch-file

I want something like this
if user inputs NK then execute IDK
if user inputs CHKDSK then execute CHKDSK
if user inputs TRUMP then execute start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy? right?

```
set/p input=
:: ^ gets input

if "%input%" == "NK" start IDK
if "%input%" == "CHKDSK" start CHKDSK
if "%input%" == "TRUMP" start IDK
:: ^ check input
```